# Extract Symbol Info Timezone Data

Tags: pine-script

Evening,

I am trying to code various selected time inputs based on the GMTOffset output. But I am not quite there.

How do I configure the time_int_01 correctly to change when the GMTOffset output changes?

Any guidance will be gratefully appreciated.

```
//@version=4
study("Initial Balance Testing GMT", overlay=true)

var int GMTOffset = hour(timenow) - hour(timenow, "GMT")


time_int_minus5 = input("1900-2000:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)
time_int_minus4 = input("2000-2100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)
time_int_minus3 = input("2100-2200:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)
time_int_minus2 = input("2200-2300:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)
time_int_minus1 = input("2300-0000:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

time_int_0 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

time_int_01 = time_int_minus5

if GMTOffset == 0
    time_int_0 := time_int_01

if GMTOffset == -1
    time_int_minus1 := time_int_01

if GMTOffset == -2
    time_int_minus2 := time_int_01

if GMTOffset == -3
    time_int_minus3 := time_int_01

if GMTOffset == -4
    time_int_minus4 := time_int_01

if GMTOffset == -5
    time_int_minus5 := time_int_01
    

// Asia START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Start
//time_int_01 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)
plotAsia = plot(highe_01, title=" Asia IB High", color=color.white, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)

//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Finish
```

#############Update 22/02/2021 @ 12:15############

The original script was based on the Initial Balance time from 00:00 to 01:00.
When viewed on a UTC = 0 symbol the IB lines up and starts from 01:00 as expected.

Please see below using BTCUSD as an example:
[image]

But when using the indicator on a symbol that is not UTC = 0 it goes out of alignment. The below examples shows GBPNZD - FSCM UTC - 5

[image]

I would like the code to look at the GMTOffset, read the output number and select a different input time.

Example:
GMTOffset = 0 then input would be "input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)"
GMTOffset = -5 then input would be "time_int_minus5 = input("1900-2000:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)"

################# 24/02/2021 @ 11:00 #####################

I cant seem to understand why I can get the time_int_01 to update its input depending on the output of GMTOffset into "in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)".

```
//@version=4
study("Initial Balance Testing GMT", overlay=true)

var int GMTOffset = hour(timenow) - hour(timenow, "GMT")

var string time_int_01 = na

if GMTOffset == 0
    time_int_01 := input("2300-0000:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

if GMTOffset == -1
    time_int_01 := input("2300-0000:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

if GMTOffset == -2
    time_int_01 := input("2200-2300:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

if GMTOffset == -3
    time_int_01 := input("2100-2200:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

if GMTOffset == -4
    time_int_01 := input("2000-2100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

if GMTOffset == -5
    time_int_01 := input("1900-2000:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)


// Asia START //
//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Start
//time_int_0 = input("0000-0100:1234567", "Asia IB Range", input.session)

in_time_int_01 = time(timeframe.period, time_int_01)

var highe_01 = 0.0
var lowe_01  = 10e10
if in_time_int_01
    if not in_time_int_01[1]
        highe_01 := high
        lowe_01  := low
    else
        highe_01 := max(high, highe_01)
        lowe_01  := min(low, lowe_01)
plotAsia = plot(highe_01, title=" Asia IB High", color=color.white, linewidth=1, style=plot.style_linebr)

//////////////////////////////////// Initial Balance Asia Finish
```

Bjorn,
Thank you for your input as I aim to update the below script I cant seen how I would do that with the code you have provided.

https://uk.tradingview.com/script/30iJncRa-Initial-Balance-Markets-Time-Zones/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot derive the integer from the variable `syminfo.timezone` because that is a string.
It is however possible to calculate the GMT Offset integer for the current symbol, like this:

```
//@version=4
study("TimeZone", "TZ", true)

var int GMTOffset = hour(timenow) - hour(timenow, "GMT")

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, close, "GMT Offset = " + tostring(GMTOffset), yloc=yloc.abovebar)
```

Which yields:

[image]

Edit: In response to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281447/extract-symbol-info-timezone-data/66281913?noredirect=1#comment117240293_66281913).
I've made a quick little mock-up with an answer to how I understand your question. It collects the highest high of the 1st hour of the symbol's session, and plots that value until after the 1st hour of the next session.

```
//@version=4
study("Initial Balance Testing GMT", "IB", overlay=true)

var int ONE_HOUR = 60*60*1000

var int IB_length = input(1, "IB Lengh in hours", minval=1)

var int     cutoff_time = na
var float   hh          = na
var float   hh_plot     = na
var bool    in_IB       = na

if change(time('D'))
    cutoff_time := time + (IB_length * ONE_HOUR)
    hh := 0 // reset highest high

in_IB := time < cutoff_time

if in_IB
    hh := max(high, hh)
else
    hh_plot := hh

plot(hh_plot, color=color.yellow)

bgcolor(in_IB ? color.yellow : na) // Give IB range a background color
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have updated my original question incase I am on the wrong path.

Comment: Evening Bjorn can you assist, I have updated my question.

Comment: I'm not at my computer right now, but what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I use my original Initial Balance Script it lines up as per configured timings when on symbol UTC 0. But when on a none UTC 0 symbol say UTC -5 everything is out of aligned by -5 hours. So what I am trying to achieve is to read the GMToffset which will then input a different time to range. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Still not sure I understand correctly. Can you update your question to include 2 screenshots of what you mean? One correct, and one incorrect? Also, please provide 2 ticker symbols on which you're testing this.

Comment: Bjorn I have updated my question. If it still does not make sense tell me and I will try again.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Time is limited lately. Still not entirely clear to me. From what I see, you want the high/low from the first hour of the session of the symbol you're on. BTCUSD is in UTC so first hour is from 00:00-01:00 UTC. GBPNZD is in UTC-5 so first hour is from 17:00-18:00 UTC-5. Correct?

Comment: Bjorn that is correct, any help will be gratefully received. When you can.

Comment: Added a quick little mock-up. Please check if it's this that you need. If not, let me know. I'll try to continue tomorrow then.

Comment: Bjorn thank you for your time. I have updated my question with where I am at the moment. I tried to understand how I could implement your suggestion to my existing script (provided link above) but I can't see how this could be achieved. In my update above I cant understand why it is not working.

Comment: Ok, so what you really want is to calculate IB range high/low for Asia/London/NY or any other session, independent of the timezone of the current symbol?

Comment: Script currently calculates IB for high/low Asia/London/NY on UTC 0, any symbol that is not UTC 0 the script does not align to the correct times. 
I am trying to get it to read the GMTOffset and change the IB times so it aligns up, unless there is a better way to achieve this. Also thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

The time zone can be taken from the variable `syminfo.timezone`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I have updated my original question incase I am on the wrong path.